# Unique Key in React/Material Ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm getting the following error "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." when i render

App.js

```
const blogPosts = [
  {
    title: '...',
    description:
      '...',
  },
  {
    title: '...',
    description:
      '...',
  },
  {
    title: '...',
    description:
      '...',
  },
];

const App = () => {
  return (
 <Blog post={blogPosts} /> )
```

Blog.js

```
<Typography gutterBottom variant="h6" component="h2" className={classes.typoTitle}>{
                    [post[0]].map(title0 => <div>{title0.title}></div>)
                  }
                  </Typography>

<Typography component="h1" variant="subtitle1" color="inherit" gutterBottom>
                    {
                      [post[0]].map(title0 => <div> {title0.description}></div>)
                    }
                  </Typography>
```

Im doing this for the 2 others props from my const in App.js with just the index of my key post changing ([post[0]],[post[1]],[post[2]]).

When Adding a key, i dont have the following error but my props are not showed.

```
 <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6" component="h2" className={classes.typoTitle}>{
                    [post[0]].map(title0 => <div key={title0.title}></div>)
                  }
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography component="h1" variant="subtitle1" color="inherit" gutterBottom>
                    {
                      [post[0]].map(title0 => <div key={title0.description}></div>)
                    }
                  </Typography>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When Adding a key, i dont have the following error but my props are
> not showed.

Because you are not passing the value to the html markup. You also need to parse the value inside the div component. I've updated your code. Please take a look.

```
<Typography gutterBottom variant="h6" component="h2" className={classes.typoTitle}>{
  [post[0]].map(title0 => <div key={title0.title}>{title0.title}</div>)
}
</Typography>
<Typography component="h1" variant="subtitle1" color="inherit" gutterBottom>{
    [post[0]].map(title0 => <div key={title0.description}>{title0.description}</div>)
  }
</Typography>
```